# app download stuck on cloud with arrow

Tags: iphone, icloud, instagram

i recently got my new phone and tried to download instagram. When i tried it looked normal and everything with the 'get' button there, but when i pressed the button it changed to the iCloud thingy with an arrow on it. Whenever i try to download it now, it just comes up with a loading circle then quickly goes back to the cloud. i have tried so many things like changing my apple ID account, making a new account, restarting the phone. Nothing works.

(it is not doing this with any other apps)

Comment: I would try a restore via iTunes

Answer (score 1):

i believe they stopped offering instagram app for ios 6 and below. what phone/ios version are you on? if youre able to upgrade the software, do that. ive heard a lot of people having issues with instagram, so theres obviously something wrong. you should try downloading the app in itunes on your computer, and then check the app to be synced with your phone when you plug it in.